# CSS -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%) don't work in IE 10 and Safari

Tags: css, filter, safari, internet-explorer-10, grayscale

I have a problem with CSS Style -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%) and filter:none don't work in IE 10 and Safari.

For Example i have Slider images but on the images is a grayscale Filter (i need this for the home site)

I implement this CSS Code:

```
.page-id-8 .slider-entry-image img{
    min-width:220px !important;
    width:220px !important;
    -webkit-filter: none!important;
    filter: url(""); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: none!important; /* IE6-9 */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

But the Slider Images are gray in IE 10 and Safari:

[image]

But i need this view:

[image]

[URL LINK](http://trautoffice.de/unternehmen/unser-team/)

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: FYI, IE doesn't support `-webkit` vendor prefix. it supports `-ms` vendor prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this for all browsers

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: url(grayscale.svg); /* Firefox 4+ */
  filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
```

refer http://labs.voronianski.com/css3-grayscale/

Comment: Referred URL is no longer valid.

Answer (score -1):

This is a cross browser solution using HTML5 and jquery

[Code](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/html5-grayscale-image-hover/comment-page-8)

[Demo](http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/html5-grayscale/)

Comment: The Demo is not working on IE Browser, it shows both images are same, do you know fix for it ?

Comment: I tested the IE9 version through IE's developer Tool. Here the result [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B87CgqdigFW-N3BGZHlleTl3U3M/view?usp=sharing). I personally ignore the IE8 and versions before that.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Its working as expected in IE 10 and IE 11.